# Which directory is better to install Symfony projects under?

Tags: symfony, ubuntu, installation

While trying to get Symfony set up, I've read different things recommending the two 'default' locations for installing Symfony projects:

- `/var/www/symfony`
- `/usr/local/symfony`

I remember reading something about an advantage of setting it up under `/var/www` - something to do with indexing possibly? Otherwise, the home area would seem 'tidier' to me (plus I assume it means less problems with changing permissions on directories?)...but then I'm still finding my way around Linux!

Comment: Is your question about production environment?

Comment: Hi @A.L I'm trying to set up the development server at the moment - although it'd be good to know for the production server too I'd you can help as I'm sure I'll hit that question at some point soon anyway :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may install it wherever you want, you can set suiting permissions with chown and chmod, i tend to this structure

```
/Projects/Projectx/web/app.php
```

a common configuration is

```
/var/www/vhosts/Projectx/web/app.php
```

Comment: Thanks @johnSmith - I like the idea of `/Projects` even more - although is there a 'benefit' of putting it in a directory under `/var` or was that bad info I heard?

Comment: the /var directory is by concept especially for variable content, but this is just the standard of use a unix filessytem